# Breakpoints are triggered incorrectly in Visual Studio Code with Vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup VS Code + Vue.js to work on some Vue.js project. I [already did some steps](https://developernote.com/2018/09/vue-js-development-tools/), but I cannot make breakpoints work correctly.

if I start the website with

```
npm run dev
```

And then start debugging in VS Code with **Debugger for Chrome** and set a breakpoint on a certain line of code in a .vue file, the line is normally marked with the red circle, but the breakpoint is triggered in different app.js file in the code like this:

```
// module
exports.push([module.i...
// exports
/***/ }),
```

what can be wrong with my debugger settings?

my config:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
  },
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach to Chrome",
    "port": 9222,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
  }
]
}

devtool: 'source-map',
```

my vue-cli version is vue@2.5.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Vue.js cookbook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html):

[Showing Source Code](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html#Showing-Source-Code-in-the-Chrome-Devtools)

In config/index.js, add:

```
devtool: 'source-map',
```

and

[Launching the Application](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html#Launching-the-Application-from-VS-Code)

Your launch.config should look like this:

```
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "vuejs: chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "breakOnLoad": true,
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with Feetball's solution from Vue.js Cookbook - it was clear to me it wasn't working correctly because breakpoints would be triggered in wrong places and the debugger would open incorrect files.

[I've had better results with this debug configuration from the Microsoft *vscode-recipes* repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/blob/master/vuejs-cli/README.md):

*The link above has detailed instructions but I'll just paste the launch config. The instructions are the same as in Vue.js cookbook*

*launch.json*:

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///*": "*",
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's the result of it working in a computed property (also works in mounted etc.):

[image]