# Breakpoints are unbound, how to map webpack correctly?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have seen several articles that offer sourceMapPathOverrides settings to get breakpoints to behave eg [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460829/breakpoints-are-triggered-incorrectly-in-visual-studio-code-with-vue-js-project)

But I found that my breakpoints would work in some files but not in others depending the webpack sourcemap. After much fiddling I think I have narrowed this down to a conflict between webpack's '/src' and '/./src' folders

My project looks like this:

[image: Project looks like this]

In the dev console webpack looks like this:

[image]

and

[image]

As you can see there are two App.vue entries, one shows my source code (the one in /src) and the other must be some webpack generated thing or similar (in /./src).

Some of my files are in /./src (appears to be all .js files eg. main.js, router/*, store/* etc.) and some are in /src (appears to be all .vue files eg. App.vue, components/*)

Now, if I use sourcemap like this in launch.json I can debug App.vue just fine, but breakpoints for files in /router and /store etc. do not work as they are not mapped:

```
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {                        
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  },
```

So I mapped as below, now breakpoints for /router etc. work but those in App.vue are broken:

```
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {                        
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",        
    "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  }
```

From what I can tell it is because I have two maps to the same App.vue source code (the one from webpack /src and from /./src).

The only way I could get around the problem is with the mapping below ie. map all files in webpack /src to my actual /src folder, then map only specific files in /./src to my /src folder (exclude the 'generated' files).
Using this means all breakpoints work as expected:

```
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {                        
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",        
    "webpack:///./src/router/*": "${webRoot}/router/*",
    "webpack:///./src/store/*": "${webRoot}/store/*",
    "webpack:///./src/main.js": "${webRoot}/main.js"                                                
  },
```

So my question is - how do I make webpack put the 'other' files in /./src and put all of my files in /src? This would allow me to remove all mappings for 'webpack:///./src'.

Currently my .vue files are in /src and my .js files are in /./src and this makes the mapping very difficult due to the duplicate component names (eg. the two App.vue files)
This is a standard vue-cli generated app, I have no custom webpack config as yet.